# Sublime Text edits since last save

Tags: sublimetext2

Can't seem to find anything online.   Frequently spend time editing multiple text documents at the same time and loose track of which ones I have edited.  When I close I am not always sure whether I have purposefully changed or accidentally edited a character in a file.   Would be great to have a feature to show the edits since last save for sublime text.

Seems like such an obvious need that I am surprised that I cannot find anything in features.  Am I missing something or am I the only one with this need?

Comment: are you just trying to find out _if_ a document has been edited, or what exactly those edits are?

Comment: standard feature already show small dot,   James Chevalier suggestion is great to add a visual cue for files that have been modified even if the sidebar is closed.  @AaronAsAChimp gave the exactly what I have been looking for.   Quickly doing a diff on what has been changed since the last save of document

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I know this already has an accepted answer, but it is not necessary to install FileDiffs or anything else. Just right click on the modified window and select `Show Unsaved Changes`.

A pane will show up at the bottom, listing the differences. There isn't an obvious way to dismiss the pane, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> will replace it with the search pane again.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer - works as described. (To clarify, you right click *in* the editing area.)

Comment: There should be some more obvious way to close that window. I do not google often for how to close a window...

Comment: ^ You must have not used Vim.

Comment: @Hashim You have a point there about Vim, but for a GUI based text editor this closing that area was a lot harder than looking through all right-click menus, visual queues and menu options and trying to find a way to close it.

Comment: Note(tested on linux): In case the **file has been moved/removed** both `FileDiffs` and builtin feature, **will not show anything.**   BUT: if unsaved and external changes occur  at the same time, and these are exactly the same, the builtin feature will again not show anything while `FileDiffs` will show: `No Difference`. This differentiation between the two cases is a plus for `FileDiffs`.

Comment: _To dismiss the pane_, I just focused my mouse on it and clicked `ESC` button and it went away.

Answer (score 8):

Add this line to your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file (If you're on a Mac, then open the Sublime Text 2 menu -> Preferences -> Settings - User):

`"highlight_modified_tabs": true`

This will highlight tabs that have unsaved changes.

Comment: That's true but doesn't really address the question, which is trying to distinguish between documents with trivial and non-trivial unsaved changes.

Comment: Good point, Steve. This answers the "did anything change?" question, but doesn't address the "what were the changes?" question.

Answer (score 6):

You may use the "Marking Changed Rows" plugin, which places a small gutter marker for lines with unsaved changes.

Comment: While this is helpful, it does leave marks even if you delete your changes, so you have to take the marks with a grain of salt.  For example, if I type a latter and hit backspace to get rid of it, there will be a mark on that row until I save again.  The only other way to get rid of the mark that I see is to undo repeatedly until you undo the original change, but that's not always practical.

Answer (score 5):

You can install the [FileDiffs](https://github.com/colinta/SublimeFileDiffs) plugin which among other useful things will give you a diff between the current (edited) file and what is saved to disk.

Comment: no instructions for adding unix standard diff.    Just used:   "cmd": ["diff", "$file1", "$file2"]

Comment: Wow, this package is fantastic.  It's nice being able to diff vs the clipboard or another tab as well.  And you can set it up to open diffs in an external program.

Answer (score 0):

### Show Unsaved Changes

Right-clicking anywhere in the file has long provided an option to show all unsaved changes.
It will list all changes in the dialog area also used for find/replace.
This should work for Sublime Text 2 *and* 3.

### Incremental Diff

A more recent version of Sublime Text 3 added an [Incremental Diff](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/incremental_diff.html) feature.

The gutter shows which lines have changed.
This works both for **unsaved changes**, as well as *changes between **file saves*** or ***git commits***.
It can be configured to show diffs against: the last saved version (git not needed), git Head, or (via the API) any other content.

#### Show modifications:

Right-Clicking the

- gutter marker, or
- any code next to the gutter marker
  (aka any area of modified code *whether or not your theme shows gutter markers*)

brings up options to:

- show the diff versions inline, or to
- open a dialog showing all tracked diffs

Or you can use the menu item:
  `Edit ->  Text -> Toggle -> Hunk Diff`
Or the shortcuts:
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>  (on Mac it's the clover icon, not Ctrl)
Or this shortcut variation, which will also close/hide all *other* diff Hunks
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>  (on Mac it's the clover icon, not Ctrl)

I'm unaware of a menu item to show all unsaved changes.

Menu Items and Shortcuts are available to navigate between changes, and revert individual (inline) changes. (see linked doc above for details).

**minor caveats**:

1. your theme must support `diff` styling to be able to ***see* the gutter markers**. The [docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/incremental_diff.html) indicate how to add custom styles if you use an older theme that does not include the necessary styles.
   However, **functionality** should still work, even if you cannot *see* the gutter markers, as long as the option is **enabled** in your `Preferences` file.
2. if you make an edit, then change it back, the buffer will still be tagged as having (2) changes, unless you reverted via Undo (ie Ctrl-Z).  It is not a "file diff" as much as it is a tracker for the edit buffer, which stores what and where.  However, the `Show Diff Hunk` option will show you whether the change was "important", an actual file diff, or not.

#### Navigate:

To navigate between modifications (*whether or not your theme shows gutter markers*):
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>
menu `Goto` -> `Next Modification`
menu `Goto` -> `Previous Modification`

#### Revert a Hunk:

With cursor over modified code or gutter (*whether or not your theme shows gutter markers*):
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>     (on Mac it's the clover icon, not Ctrl)
menu `Edit` -> /`Text` -> `Revert Modification`

This will only act on the `diff Hunk` that is at the location of your cursor.
It will not have any effect if your cursor is not in an area of modified code / diff Hunk.

### Here are the Sublime Text 3 SETTINGS that control the Incremental Diff feature:

**`mini_diff`** controls the incremental diff functionality (on / off / on for Git only)
Valid values include:

```
true   –  always enable incremental diff (the DEFAULT) (Git or Not-Git)
"auto" –  enable  incremental diff for files in a Git repository (only)
false  –  disable incremental diff
```

**`git_diff_target`** controls the behavior of incremental diff for files in a Git repository
Valid values include:

```
"index" – diff against the Git index (aka staged for commit), (the DEFAULT)
"head"  – diff against the file at HEAD (aka last commit in checked out branch)
```